# Prevent browser from redirecting CNAME record to A record in URL address bar

Tags: redirect, caching, dns, browser-cache, cname

There seems to be either a DNS configuration issue or something else I'm not understanding, with respect to CNAMEs and redirection.

I have a CNAME record:

```
CNAME     myserver.example.com     www.example2.com
```

www.example2.com points to an A record.

I ran a Wireshark to get a better understanding of what's going on.

The very first time I type the CNAME in the browser's URL address bar, the Wireshark shows it does a DNS lookup for the A record and the browser redirects to this A record (www.example2.com), as evidenced by what appears in the URL address bar. It's performing a redirect.

The second time I type the CNAME in the URL address bar, I don't see a DNS lookup. It automatically resolves to www.example2.com and the URL address bar redirects from the CNAME I typed to www.example2.com. I checked with Fiddler and Fiddler doesn't even show the CNAME record. It's as if I typed www.example2.com in the URL address bar, from the perspective of Fiddler.

As best as I can tell, the browser has its own DNS cache and resolves the CNAME record to the A record. No need to go out to the name server. So, that explains that. But what I don't understand is why is the browser performing a redirect from the CNAME record to the A record, as evidenced by the URL address bar changing from myserver.example.com to www.example2.com. Is there something I'm missing? Is there some DNS configuration step that has to be performed on the name server for example.com and/or the name server for example2.com?

I want myserver.example.com to be a vanity URL. It shouldn't redirect.

Any help on this matter would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The redirect comes from webserver/application, look there (DNS is not the culprit here).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. What doesn't is why is WireShark and Fiddler, on the second go-around, not showing the redirect? I type myserver.example.com and I don't see evidence of a redirect to www.example2.com. It's as if I typed www.example2.com directly. It's as if the browser is not caching the redirect action but the final product of the redirect. Maybe if the web server/app redirect was for A to A record, instead of CNAME to A record, I'd see the redirect in Wireshark and Fiddler.

Comment: DNS records are cached, and HTTP `301 Redirect`s are cached also, browser will immediately go to the new location. You can see it in Network tab of browser developer console (`Status Code:301 Moved Permanently (from disk cache)` or similar)

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you. If you can put it in the form of an answer, I can checkmark it. Thanks so much.